# Get string value using php preg_match_all?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match-all

I have a string like this:

```
02:58:51 05/02/2018 Username: jasonkot |  Password: marryhost@992 | OTP TYPE: SMS
```

How can i get the value of Username and Password using preg_match_all function as new array ?

Thank you!

Comment: Please, post your current regular expression that not works.

Comment: Just explode on `|` and then explode `1` on `: `

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- that said, locate the documentation of the function online and read the provided examples. If your problems persist, come back and ask specific questions, but don't dump your homework here hoping someone will do it for you.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks. But actually i have tried my regular expression what i've thought it was right on www.phpliveregex.com but all failed the i went to here. I'm not a lazy bum.

Comment: Well, but you can't come up with any example code that details your failure? Code that was written after research and where the behaviour you expect after careful research does not match the actual one? You claim that you havn't been lazy, so extract a minimal example, too! This is not just to make sure you are not lazy, but it also ensures that you don't ask stupid questions that could have been solved yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: [`(Username|Password):\s(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/vYXbGX/4)

Details:

- `()` Capturing group
- `\s` Matches any whitespace character
- `\S` Matches any non-whitespace character
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times

**PHP code**:

```
$string= '02:58:51 05/02/2018 Username: jasonkot |  Password: marryhost@992 | OTP TYPE: SMS ';

preg_match_all('~(Username|Password):\s(\S+)~', $string, $matches);
print_r(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Username] => jasonkot
    [Password] => marryhost@992
)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks. Your regex looks so easy. At first i thought it was so hard.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this without regex via PHP's [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
$string = "02:58:51 05/02/2018 Username: jasonkot |  Password: marryhost@992 | OTP TYPE: SMS ";
$exploded = explode("|", $string);

$array = [
  "username" => trim(explode(": ", $exploded[0])[1]), 
  "password" => trim(explode(": ", $exploded[1])[1])
];

print_r($array);
```

First, `explode()` the main string into multiple parts (By the "|" symbol):

```
$string = "02:58:51 05/02/2018 Username: jasonkot |  Password: marryhost@992 | OTP TYPE: SMS ";
$exploded = explode("|", $string);
```

This will return an array of parts of your string that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 02:58:51 05/02/2018 Username: jasonkot 
    [1] =>   Password: marryhost@992 
    [2] =>  OTP TYPE: SMS 
)
```

Then, `explode()` each segment AGAIN (By the ":" symbol), and select the 2nd array value that is returned from exploding for the username and the password.

```
$array = [
  "Username" => trim(explode(": ", $exploded[0])[1]), 
  "Password" => trim(explode(": ", $exploded[1])[1])
];
```

As you can see, I explode `$exploded[0]` again, but at the `": "` symbol, which will leave me with the string broken into 2 parts, where the 2nd part os the username/password itself.

Be sure to use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to get rid of any whitespace that may be left over.

The above will return:

```
Array
(
    [Username] => jasonkot
    [Password] => marryhost@992
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex like this ^.*Username:\s*(\S*)\s*\|\s*Password:\s*(\S*)\s*\|.*$ demo:https://www.phpregexonline.com/q/2